# Importing all CSV files from a directory into Datastore in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv, datastore

I have 450 `*.csv` files in a directory and I want to collect/import all of them into **one** `datastore` for further processing. I have used the following code for collecting all the CSV files into one datastore.

```
       Path = 'Data/Dataset Collection/';
       Files = dir(Path);
       for k = 1 : length(Files)
          FileNames = Files(k).name;

          if (~strcmp(FileNames, '.'))
              if (~strcmp(FileNames, '..'))
                  ds = datastore([Path  FileNames], 'TreatAsMissing', 'NA');

                  if k == 3
                  ds_All = ds;
                  else
                  ds_All = [ds_All ds];
                  end
              end
          end
```

But, I am facing with this error:

> Array formation and parentheses-style indexing with objects of class
>   'matlab.io.datastore.TabularTextDatastore' is not allowed.  Use
>   objects of class 'matlab.io.datastore.TabularTextDatastore' only as
>   scalars or use a cell array.

I have two questions:

1- How can I use the better coding to only use **one** datesotre (`only ds`), **NOT** two (`ds and ds_All`).

2- If my solution is well enough, how can I overcome the error?

Comment: I believe the error comes from the line `ds_All = [ds_All ds];`. What is this line supposed to do?

Comment: @AmosEgel , I am going to collect every single ds which is every single csv files, into one final datastore as ds_All. Otherwise, How can I collect them one-by-one into one single datastore?

Comment: @SardarUsama, yes, because I wana use MapReduce and csv files all together are 2GB data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Matlab online help](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datastore.html):

> `ds = datastore(location)` creates a datastore from the collection of data specified by location. A datastore is a repository for collections of data that are too large to fit in memory. After creating ds, you can read and process the data.

So it seems you can just initialize your datastore by the folder where the files are in. Have you tried

```
Path = 'Data/Dataset Collection/';
ds = datastore(Path);
```